# Is it possible to have a constructor that assigns a value to the instance as a whole?

Tags: c#

If I have a class like this:

```
class myClass
{
    string foo;
    string bar;

    public myClass(string foo, string bar)
    {
        //does some stuff here
        (myClass)deserializer.Deserialize(reader); //assign the return value to the instance
    }

}
```

Something that would achieve this:

```
public myClass(string foo, string bar)
    {
        //does some stuff here
        myClass tempobject = (myClass)deserializer.Deserialize(reader); //this method has a return value of type myClass
        this.foo = tempObject.foo;
        this.bar = tempObject.bar;
    }
```

`SomeMethod` returns a value of type `myClass`. Can I assign this returned value to the instance of myClass that invoked the constructor?

Comment: No. An instance cannot "replace itself". The best you can do is copy all state from another instance. If that is good enough, you have to decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that isn't possible.

What you could do is make `SomeMethod` static and the constructor private. This is called the [Factory Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx), as you have a method used to create instances of your class. The factory pattern is often used to create instances of various different concrete classes at runtime.

---

As you've updated your question to say that the method isn't in your class, then i think the best option is to make a method in your class that takes another instance of the class, then in that method, copy all properties. You'd call that in your constructor.

Comment: Modified the question to specify what exactly `SomeMethod` is.

Answer (score 2):

No -- the constructor doesn't return an instance to the class you've created because the object has to be instantiated **before** the constructor gets called. The constructor just does initialization work on the class that was created moments ago.

Instead, you'll have to use a "factory" pattern, like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static SomeClass CreateNew(string foo, string bar) {
        if (SOME_CONDITION) {
            // use our SomeMethod
            return SomeMethod(foo,bar);
        } else {
            // otherwise use the normal constructor
            return new SomeClass(x,y);
        }
    }
}

// ... elsewhere...

    SomeClass foo = Someclass.CreateNew("x","y");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass
{
    string foo;
    string bar;

    public myClass(string foo, string bar)
    {
        //does some stuff here
        mYclass result = SomeMethod(foo,bar); //this method has a return value of type myClass
        this.foo = result.foo;
        this.bar = result.bar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a static method that allows you to create an object from your reader like this:

```
class myClass  
{      
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }        


    public myClass()      
    {          
        //does some stuff here     
    }

    public static myClass FromReader(Reader reader)
    {
        return (myClass)deserializer.Deserialize(reader); 
    }
}
```

and use it in your code like this:

```
myClass newMyClass = myClass.FromReader(reader);
```